# Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I'm having problems with a Map Fragment. The error message is saying *Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment*. I tried changing to `extends FragmentActivity` together with `GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()` but that caused problems with my `onCreateView` line of code instead.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Fragment01 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false);

    // Get a handle to the Map Fragment
    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

replace

```
getFragmentManager
```

with

```
getSupportFragmentManager
```

`getFragmentManager` returns the instance of androids api `fragment`(available from v11+) class but you have imported  `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

So either call `getSupportFragmentManager` or change inports.

getSupportFragmentManager is available only in `FragmentActivity` class.

So you need to first put this fragment inside a `FragmentActivity` (extent `FragmentActivity` not `Activity`) and then in `onActivityCreated` method of fragment get the activity reference and call `getSupportFragmentManager`. e.g.

```
myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

for ref.:
[How can I access getSupportFragmentManager() in a fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237531/how-can-i-access-getsupportfragmentmanager-under-fragment)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and I get an error saying *The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Fragment01*?

Comment: check my edit. Google "getsupportfragmentmanager in fragment" to know more about how to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the `FragmentActivity` class, only the `Fragment` class, otherwise my the `onSelectFragment` section in my `MainActivity`gets all messed up. I've found another solution which I'm currently testing.

Answer (score 4):

Try these lines of code, they may help you:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
Google_Map = supportMapFragment.getMap();
```