# How to get getSupprtFragmentManager() from a fragmenty

Tags: android, fragment

getSupportFragmentManager not working inside a fragment

```
Fragment tFragment = MainActivity.newInstance();

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tFragment);
        ft.commit();
```

any answer will be appreciable

Comment: Try this `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()....`

Comment: i tried getActivity() but not working

Comment: @je show me your code properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i access getSupportFragmentManager under fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237531/how-can-i-access-getsupportfragmentmanager-under-fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private FragmentActivity myContext;
```

override onAttach method of your fragment :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

When you need to get Support fragment manager call :

```
FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

or

```
FragmentManager fragManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

see below link:-

[How can I access getSupportFragmentManager() in a fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237531/how-can-i-access-getsupportfragmentmanager-under-fragment)

Comment: @jekiran you can also use getActivity() instead of mContext

Comment: @jekiran it means you achieve your goal ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import fragment as :

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```