# Using getFragmentManager() vs getSupportFragmentManager()?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

When should I use getFragmentManager() when showing DialogFragments, and when should I use getSupportFragmentManager()?

Currently, I am showing my DialogFragments as follows:

```
myDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "My Dialog Fragment");
```

Comment: See also this one [getFragmentManager vs getSupportFragmentManager ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38453111/1820553)

Answer (score 20):

If you are using API >=  14, then use `getFragmentManager()` and while using Support Package you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

For Example Android Support Package v4 or v13.

Comment: Just to confirm - if I am using API version 14, I should be using getSupportFragmentManager()?

Comment: if using API version 14 using getFragmentManager() sorry for misleading i will change my answer for better understanding.

Comment: Fragment manger will work API>=11 see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html

Answer (score 7):

When you are using *`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`* then you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` and if you are using *`android.app.FragmentManager`* then use `getFragmentManager()`.