# android: getFragmentManger and getSupportFragmentManger

Tags: android

from some of the answer such as
[Using getFragmentManager() vs getSupportFragmentManager()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306197/using-getfragmentmanager-vs-getsupportfragmentmanager)
I find that getFragmentManager() is used for API>=14,
and getSupportFragmentManager() will be used in support lib such as v4 which also support older API.

So my question is should I just use getSupportFragmentManager (import the support.v4 for each classes) so that my application can be used in any API version?
And are there any different I should know between these 2 FragmentManager?

Comment: hi, usally i use supportfragments you never know when a client decide that his application should also run on older androids :p, here is another [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295497/fragment-or-support-fragment) about this topic

Comment: answer to the first question is, unfortunately, another question: What is your minSDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in supporting API versions that do not have Fragments, then by all means use the `FragmentActivity` and `getSupportFragmentManager()` patterns.

Even if you are not targeting  an API below 14, it may be a good idea to use the support library.  Classes in the support library can be updated by you, the developer, whenever Google releases a bugfix/feature in the library that you are interested in.  If you use a framework class, you only get the updates when your users get a firmware update, which we all know can take a while. Using the support library means all users are using the same "latest-and-greatest" classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for Fragment, just use `getSupportFragmentManager`, then your app for Fragment can be compatible backward to old API levels, normally `minSDKversion = 7` is enough. However if you really want your app to get compitability with most API levels, then there still many other components your app concerning need use support library, such as `ActionBar`, etc..

For more info, please go through Android Docs: [Support Library Features](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html)