# How to open date picker dialog?

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

How Can I open Date Picker Dialog?

I tried using this code, but this doesn't do anything. I believe it has been deprecated, but I haven't found the solution yet.

```
mDOB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

        }
    });
```

Comment: [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) give this link a try

Comment: Are you calling show method in showDialog method?

Comment: `public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}`

Comment: just have a look at the link their everything is their

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // get month, year and day
        }
    }
```

and call this dialog by using this...

```
new DatePickerFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "datepicker");
```

Comment: your code works. Thank you. the documentation says I need to use getSupportFragmentManager. That doesn't work for me but getFragmentManager works. do you know why?

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306197/using-getfragmentmanager-vs-getsupportfragmentmanager