# Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager ( )' inside Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragment

I found the message Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager ( )'
I want to fragment as activity.
because I want to use Maps on the tabs swipe.

```
public class PETAcikarangsukatani extends Fragment {
Context context;

private static final LatLng SUKATANI = new LatLng(-6.171327, 107.178108);
private static final LatLng WRPOJOK = new LatLng(-6.222411, 107.162158);
private static final LatLng PILAR = new LatLng(-6.257033, 107.156472);
private static final LatLng CIKARANG = new LatLng(-6.256073, 107.143984);


GoogleMap googleMap;
final String TAG = "PathGoogleMapActivity";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_path_google_map, container, false);
    context = rootView.getContext();

    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = fm.getMap();
```

Comment: Map is a fragment or is a container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access getSupportFragmentManager() in a fragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237531/how-can-i-access-getsupportfragmentmanager-in-a-fragment)

Comment: here it is explained properly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWk3PXV6O98

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Inside a `Fragment` subclass you have to use `getFragmentManager` in place of `getSupportFragmentManager`. You will get the support one if the import are from the support library.

Comment: what does it mean, *but still not running* ?

Comment: also you have to change in fragmrnt xml, from: android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" to android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Comment: Consider using getChildFragmentManager() inside a fragment instead of getFragmentManager() or getSupportFragmentManager().

Answer (score 50):

For my case,
I made sure that **Fragment** class is imported from

> android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Not from

> android.app.Fragment

Then I have used

> getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

And now its working. If I use activity instance which I got in onAttach() is not working also.

Comment: This is an importante note: you must add v4 android support to work.

Answer (score 41):

Extends **FragmentActivity** instead of **Activity**

Comment: As you can see, the topicstarter was asking about `Fragment` issue not `Activity` one.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Oops! you didn't directly answer the asker question, but mine! you solved it. thank you +1

Comment: you can also use AppCompatActivity

Comment: Thanks! It's working. My class has been inherited from FragmentActivity and compilation ended fine.

Answer (score 18):

Use `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 16):

**Replace `getSupportFragmentManager()`** with  `getFragmentManager()`
if you are working in api 21. 
 **OR**
If your app supports versions of Android older than 3.0, be sure you've set up your Android project with the support library as described in Setting Up a Project to Use a Library and use `getSupportFragmentManager()` this time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Maybe you want to read [our editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your post formatting (esp. section on [Code Spans](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)).

Answer (score 8):

Also you can use `AppCompatActivity` instead of Activity.
Then `getSupportFragmentManager()` will work.
And also not forget to make your App theme extend AppCompat theme in this case

Answer (score 5):

As per the documentation, getSupportFragmentManager() is present only inside AppCompatActivity class. It is not present inside Activity class. So make sure your class extends AppCompatActivity class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`getSupportFragmentManager()` is not part of `Fragment`, so you cannot get it here that way. You can get it from parent `Activity` (so in `onAttach()` the earliest) using normal

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

or you can try [getChildFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()), which is in scope of Fragment, but requires API17+

Answer (score 3):

> getFragmentManager()

just try this.it worked for my case

Answer (score 2):

you should use

```
getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager() like
//in my fragment 
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)    
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

I have also this issues but resolved after adding `getActivity()` before `getSupportFragmentManager`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting "Cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager()", try using

```
this.getSupportFragmentManager()
```

It works for me when dealing with DialogFragments in android

Answer (score 1):

If you're instantiating an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` class, the you have to call `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` to get rid of the cannot-resolve problem. However the official Android docs on Fragment by Google tends to over look this simple problem and they still document it without the `getActivity()` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

For me I made sure to import v4 like this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

Then used:

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all above, but none working

Finally tried this my own

```
getBaseActivity().getFragmentManager()
```

and is working .. :)