# Calling SupportFragmentManager from PauseHandler implementation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-handler

I am trying to implement the PauseHandler described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8122789/1977132

My activity is an ActionBarActivity, the code in the processMessage method which brings up a dialog gives the error `Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager'`

Following the suggestion here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27425568/1977132

I tried to change it to getFragmentManager() but then I get the error `Cannot resolve method 'show(android.app.FragmentManager(), java.lang.String'`

I have pasted what I believe to be the relevant code here:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class PlaySession extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            final Fragment state = new State();
            final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(state, State.TAG);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    public static class rescanDialogBox extends DialogFragment {
        final static String TAG = "RESCAN";

        public static rescanDialogBox newInstance(int title) {
            rescanDialogBox frag = new rescanDialogBox();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("title", title);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            String title = "Rescan?";
            String message = "No Bluetooth LE devices found. Do you want to rescan? If you keep getting this message check the battery of your Bluetooth device.";

            AlertDialog.Builder myDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            myDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
            myDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
            myDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((PlaySession) getActivity()).yesRescan();
                    }
                });
            myDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((PlaySession) getActivity()).noRescan();
                    }
                });

            AlertDialog myDialog = myDialogBuilder.create();
            myDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            return myDialog;
        }
    }

    public void yesRescan() {
        //rescan
    }

    public void noRescan() {
        //do nothing
    }

    final static class State extends Fragment {
        static final String TAG = "State";
        public PauseHandlerImplementation handler = new PauseHandlerImplementation();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            handler.setActivity(getActivity());
            handler.resume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            handler.pause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            handler.setActivity(null);
        }
    }


    static class PauseHandlerImplementation extends PauseHandler {
        protected Activity activity;

        final void setActivity(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        final protected void processMessage(String toDo) {
            final Activity activity = this.activity;

            if (activity != null) {
                if(toDo.equals("OFFER_RESCAN")) {
                    //offer rescan
                    DialogFragment newFragment = new rescanDialogBox();
                    newFragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), rescanDialogBox.TAG);
                    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

                } else if (toDo.equals("OFFER_DEVICES")) {
                    //offer devices
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course there is also the code for the PauseHandler which extends Handler and the code for the dialog box but that was/is working ok so doesn't seem relevant.

**EDIT**
Added code for the rescan dialog box, this dialog box worked fine before I added the PauseHandler but I needed to add support for the case where the user navigates away from the app while the scan is in progress, hence the need for the PauseHandler

Comment: what is rescanDialogBox? Could you share the code for it?

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 I've added the code for the rescanDialogBox, thank you for any ideas you have.

Comment: Ok, rescanDialogBox looks fine.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `activity` variable inside `processMessage` when you already have it as a member field of `PauseHandlerImplementaion` class? Also have you tried using getActivity() instead?

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 I was just copying the code from the first answer I linked to, they seemingly duplicate the activity variable. I don't know why. I've tried replacing it with getActivity(), but then the error changes to `Cannot resolve method getActivity()`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `ActionBarActivity`is now deprecated. You probably should use `AppCompatActivity` to be able to support previous Android version.

Second, you should specify the container where to put your State fragment, with the method `.replace(int ontainerViewId, Fragment fragment)`. Your method should look like this:

```java
final Fragment state = new State();
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.your_container_id, state);
ft.commit();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The State fragment itself doesn't have any UI so doesn't get added to a container (onCreateView returns null - see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html ). Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours, I think you should change

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
```

to

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```

in your `DialogFragment` class