# How to call fragment from an adapter? getting error at getFragmentManager

Tags: android

I tried calling fragment from an adapter but I am getting an error at `getFtragmentManager`

**AdapterClass**

```
holder.track_order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TrackOrderFragment fragment2 = new TrackOrderFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment2);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

> error: Cannot resolve method 'getFragmentManager()'

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30860006/6067892)?

Comment: `getFragmentManager()` is method of some class definitely not of any `Adapter` class . So what you need to call a virtual method of class ? Its **Object**.

Comment: @ADM Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

is `holder.track_order.setOnClickListener` in your fragment class?
If not pass the reference of fragment to the class where you are calling it and call it like:

```
fragment.getActivity(). getFragmentManager();
```

Comment: `holder.track_order.setOnClickListener` it from an adapter class

Comment: getFragmentManager() is a method of Fragment class, you can't call it without the reference of fragment in adapter.

Comment: You are right, but I am getting an error like you cannot resolve... Can you please show me an example of how to call from an adapter class.

Comment: pass a reference of fragment in adapter like: Adapter adapter = new Adapter(Fragment fragment);

Answer (score 0):

It says you "Cannot resolve method 'getFragmentManager()" because Java doesn't see your method.
You need to create this getFragmentManager() if it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: What do you mean create `getFragmentManager()` this is a method from predefined class

Comment: No. `getFragmentManager()` is a built-in method of `Activity`.