# How to use bottom sheet in fragment class instead of Activity Class?

Tags: android, fragment, bottom-sheet

I am trying to use the bottom sheet in a click listener but I am getting an error on this line.

**bottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager())**

> Cannot resolve method 'show(?, java.lang.String)' Cannot resolve
>   method 'getSupportFragmentManager()

I want to use the bottom sheet in a fragment class.

**SubCategoryDetailFragment.java**

```
  public class SubCategoryDetailFragment extends Fragment {

        TextView txtv_sort;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_category_detail, container, false);
            toolbar = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toggle = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getToggle();
            shimmerContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);
            recyclerView_subcatDetail = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_subCategoryDetail);

           txtv_sort = view.findViewById(R.id.txtv_sort);

            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back);
            toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
                }
            });


         txtv_sort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
                    bottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

    }
```

**BottomSheetFragment.java**

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends Fragment {


    public BottomSheetFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false);
    }

}
```

**fragment_bottom_sheet.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    tools:context=".Fragments.BottomSheetFragment">

    <!-- NOTE: This list should be displayed in a list
    instead of nested layouts -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"

        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:tint="#737373" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Preview"
            android:textColor="#737373"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"

        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:tint="#737373" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Share"
            android:textColor="#737373"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"

        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:tint="#737373" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Get link"
            android:textColor="#737373"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"

        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:tint="#737373" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Make a Copy"
            android:textColor="#737373"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"

        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:tint="#737373" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Email a Copy"
            android:textColor="#737373"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager ( )' inside Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425547/cannot-resolve-method-getsupportfragmentmanager-inside-fragment)

Comment: Extends your `BottomSheetFragment` with `BottomSheetDialogFragment` instead of fragment

Comment: It should be `class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

Comment: yeah the error are gone...thank you

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use `BottomSheetDialogFragment` in `Fragment` simply like below code,

```
BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetFragment = new YourBottomSheetFragmentClass();
bottomSheetFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
```

Or if you want to pass some data to `BottomSheetDialogFragment` use below code, with `newInstance` you can send and retrieve data.

Inside your fragment class :

```
BottomSheetDialogFragment myBottomSheet = YourBottomSheetFragmentClass.newInstance(SendString);            
myBottomSheet.show(getFragmentManager(),myBottomSheet.getTag());
```

In your BottomSheetFragment class, add below line

```
static YourBottomSheetFragmentClass newInstance(String retrieveString) {
        YourBottomSheetFragmentClass f = new YourBottomSheetFragmentClass();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("getString", retrieveString);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
            return new f();
        }
```

Also extends your `YourBottomSheetFragmentClass` with `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

Comment: what is FollowupFragment_BottomSheet here?

Comment: Instead of there, you can use your BottomsheetFragment class name.

Comment: if i use my BottomsheetFragment class then error is coming on new instance  BottomSheetFragment.newInstance();

Comment: Answer edited, please check and let me know if any queries.

Comment: but getFragmentManager() method is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#pass-parent-child)
in order to pass data between parent and child fragment do this:
to launc

to launch the bottom sheet:

```
button.setOnClickListener{
    val sortRecipesBottomSheet = SortRecipesBottomSheet()
    sortRecipesBottomSheet.show(childFragmentManager,sortRecipesBottomSheet.tag)
}
```

in the same fragment write this code to receive the result from the bottom sheet

```
 childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(
            "requestKey",
            viewLifecycleOwner
        ) { key, bundle ->
            val result = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
            println("heeeeeeere: "+ result)
            // Do something with the result
        }
```

in your bottomsheet fragment in order to send the result back write this:

```
 view.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.sortByName).setOnClickListener {
            parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResult(
                "requestKey",
                bundleOf("bundleKey" to SortType.ByName.key)
            )
            dismiss()
        }
```

in parent fragment in `show()` method you are sending `childFragmentManager` and you are using `childFragmentManager` to listen to the result and in bottomsheet you are using `parentFragmentManager` to set the result for the parent fragment to read.