# Google Map Options Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add attributes to the Google Map fragment in my Android application. Am I finding the map correctly? How would I implement the example below? Source code below.

**Example (I want to add something like this)**

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
        .title("Marker"));
}
```

**fragment1_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#D70B0D"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/textView6"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRespond"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnRespond"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/button_animation"
        android:padding="5dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment1.java

```
package ie.itsligo.medication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);

        Fragment map = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnRespond);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Are Now Active! Swipe Left For Individual Details & Medical Information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return view; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast your `fragment` to a `MapFragment` in your `onCreateView` method and then call your map async like so

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Taken from the google map docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

Then `OnMapReady` will be called automatically when the map is loaded.

Comment: get this error = "Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment"

Comment: Try changing `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: new error = "The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Fragment1"

Comment: Try this first, replace it with `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`, and if that doesn't work check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237531/how-can-i-access-getsupportfragmentmanager-under-fragment) which i believe is trying to do the same thing.

Comment: is it because I am using onCreateView instead of onCreate because the same thing happens when I try and find a textview by id "txt1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txt1);" instead of "txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);" because I get a error on the findViewById part

Comment: Alright I pulled up some old code where I used maps. I instantiate the map in the `onActivityCreated` method with this line `map = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.eventCreateMap)).getMap()` (Change the id to whatever you need). However `getMap` is deprecated so use `getMapAsync` if you can. Lemme know if that gets you anywhere

Comment: No problem, sorry it took so many comments. Be sure to make the question as answered.