# Android Tabbed Activity with Fragments and TabLayout

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Is it possible to create a tabbed activity with a tablayout inside just one fragment ? I want this tablayout to slide from all fragments of the activity but I want it inside just one fragment. Here is an image for a better explanation.
[tabbed activity tablayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BVHj.png)
PS.: got the original image from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021245/android-tablayout-inside-a-tab-of-another-tablayout) and edited it

Comment: use page slider with fragment adapter.
see this ,https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

or you can use bottom navigation bar

see this https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0

Comment: Is there a tutorial like for dummies ? I'm new in android programming