# Error:(26, 24) error: incompatible types: class cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: android, arrays, android-fragments

I'm trying to do a Menu app in Android through fragments

All the classes I'm sending extend from a Fragment and that's what the array fragment it's asking me but still say is not.

[image]

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class  Actividades extends AppCompatActivity implements InterfaceMenu {

    //Array para menu y fragments

    Fragment[] array_frag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividades);

        //Obtener del menu el boton pulsado
        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        menu(extras.getInt("BotonPulsado"));


        array_frag = new Fragment[3];
        array_frag[0]= new Lintern();
        array_frag[1]= new Nivel();
        array_frag[2]= new Service();
    }


    @Override
    public void menu(int frag_boton) {

        //obtener fragmentmanager y empezar transaccion
        FragmentManager mimanager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mitransaction = mimanager.beginTransaction();
        //mandamos el id de donde se van a
        // cargar los fragments y que fragment vamos a mandar
        mitransaction.replace(R.id.actividades,array_frag[frag_boton]);
        mitransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Here it's one of my classes they are all empty just like this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Lintern extends Fragment {


    public Lintern() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lintern, container, false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, you can't use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` with `getFragmentManager()`. You need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead.

Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20237647/3758972

Comment: i tried what is there but still not working i'll the  image  from the error so u can't check it

Comment: ok i can't change the image but!!! the error say's  "Imcompatible types." Required:adroid.app.Fragment

Comment: Yeah, you need to use `android.app.Fragment` instead of `v4.Fragment` with `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Thankx Nitesh u wise man :3