# Time Picker - no Dialog showing

Tags: android, time, alarm, picker

Good evening,
today I am trying to build a Time Picker inside Android Studio for this I watched the video of CodingInFlow. The difference is, I am building the time picker inside a Fragment this means I somehow cannot use `getSupportFragmentManager`. Well I got the rest right but after clicking the button after which the Time Picker should show up nothing happens the time picker doesn't show up it's like the button doesn't even have a OnClick. I think this might have to do something with this `getSupportFragmentManager` thing. I would like to show you my code.

**AlarmFragment.java:**

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View fraAla = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);


    Button bAlarm = fraAla.findViewById(R.id.buttonAlarm);
    bAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment zeitwaehlen = new AlarmTimePicker();
            zeitwaehlen.show(getFragmentManager(), "time picker");
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    TextView txtAlarm = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewAlarm);
    txtAlarm.setText("Stunde: " + hourOfDay + " Minute: " + minute);

}
```

**AlarmTimePicker.java:**

```
    @NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar k = Calendar.getInstance();
    int stunde = k.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = k.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), stunde, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
```

**fragment_alarm.xml:**

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewAlarm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttonAlarm"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:text="time"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAlarm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="open time picker" />
```

When I try to write `getSupportFragmentManager` the App crashes.
I also tried to do it like this guy here said: [How can I access getSupportFragmentManager() in a fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237531/how-can-i-access-getsupportfragmentmanager-in-a-fragment)
But as I am new to coding I didn't really get what he meant with
    `FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();`
I understand he created a new variable but when I try to do the same (of course I changed `myContext`) I do not know how to call this variable later in the code. Because when I type the name of the variable it's underlined red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `oncreatview()` method you are returnig a duplicate layout. You need to return `fraAla` instead of `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);`

Answer (score -1):

In the `onCreatView()` method you are returnig a return `fraAla` instead of `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);`

Because create two references of view in on createview.