# How to fix supportFragmentManager?

Tags: android, kotlin, supportmapfragment, child-fragment

Im trying to put google maps into `SupportMapFragment` on my `MainActivity` file like these ways:

```
val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as? SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
```

and

```
val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
```

And modifying my `content_main.xml` like:

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

and

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="13"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

but the application is working like the next way:
[image: Instead map should be displayed in white area]

Any advice?

**EDIT**
This is my `Activity_Main.xml`:

```
<include
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

<!--<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />-->
```

ps. I removed the `<fragment>` tag to debug some parts.

Comment: When do you actually add MapFragment to the FragmentManager using a FragmentTransaction?

Comment: The code does not match the XML the least, because there is no `R.id.map`.

Comment: Could you check my last edited? Thank you.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'm very new developing android applications. I have not a lot idea of this.

Comment: @Mareyes Why you are including layout instead of fragment ?

Comment: Follow this link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237531/how-can-i-access-getsupportfragmentmanager-in-a-fragment

Comment: @ManiKandan to experiment different ways, anyway is not working the fragment.

Comment: Self-answer notes that the Fragment was simply never added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it; as the guys taugh me in the comments, I'm going to post for future references if someone has same situation:

```
val mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, mapFragment)
            .commit()
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
```

Thank you.