# Android: calling `getSupportFragmentManager` from `Activity`

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a class `myClass : UnityPlayerActivity()` which derives from `UnityPlayerActivity`. This class is generated as following (and I'd rather not alter it)

```
public class UnityPlayerActivity extends Activity implements IUnityPlayerLifecycleEvents
```

I now need to call `getSupportedFragmentManager` but this is unavailable from a class which does not derive from `AppCompatActivity`. So I was wondering If I could someway get the `SupportFragmentManager` without changing the Unity generated class.

Comment: I believe this SO has the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237531/how-can-i-access-getsupportfragmentmanager-in-a-fragment

Comment: No, `getFragmentManager` is deprecated and also won't do what I want: showing a dialog which explicitely needs a `SupportedFragmentManager`

Comment: Why not use AppCompatActivity? If you don't mind me asking!